# How to prevent new line in StyledText after Enter pressed

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, newline, styledtext

I need to prevent TextViewer making new lines after I press Enter key in case of preventNewLines flag is enabled.

I have this piece of code:

```
TextViewer myTextViewer = new TextViewer (myGroup, SWT.V_SCROLL 
                                          | SWT.FULL_SELECTION 
                                          | SWT.BORDER | SWT.WRAP);
myTextViewer.setDocument(new Document(myText));
StyledText myStyledText = myTextViewer.getTextWidget();

myStyledText.addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {
     @Override
     public void keyTraversed(TraverseEvent e) {
         if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_RETURN) {
            if (preventNewLines) 
               e.doit = false;
         }
     }
});
```

But it makes new lines anyway... What am I doing wrong?
Could anybody please post me the correct code how to prevent it?

**EDIT:**
OK, I've found the answer by luck, I hope it helps to someone else, maybe...

```
myStyledText.addVerifyKeyListener(new VerifyKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void verifyKey(VerifyEvent e) {
        if (preventNewLines && 
            (e.keyCode == SWT.CR || e.keyCode == SWT.KEYPAD_CR)) {
           e.doit = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You should answer your own question then check it as answered as it's still an open question.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7589098/18445

```
@Override
public boolean isNavigationEvent(ColumnViewer viewer, Event event) {
    return event.keyCode == SWT.CR || event.keyCode == SWT.KEYPAD_CR;
}
```